# How can I parse a script tag, and get a variable inside of it, without using eval()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that generates this code **MULTIPLE** times *(content of fields array is different)*:

```
<script language="javascript">
try {
  var fields = Array();
  fields = {id:1,type:text,value:banana};
  fields = {id:2,type:text,value:apple};
  fields = {id:3,type:number,value:10};
}
</script>
```

Then I have a function that accesses the fields array:

```
function functionName(fieldId){
  var allFields = eval('fields');
  if (allFields) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < allFields.length; i++) {
        var field = allFields[i];
        if(field.id == fieldId){
          return field;
        }
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

The problem is, that I want to use this function in multiple places, accessing the fields array of DIFFERENT script tags. Right now, that function always just gets the first script tag, and I need to be able to scope it to a specific script tag.

Since I cannot change the actual function that generates the array, I CAN change the ID of the script tag like so:

```
    <script language="javascript" id="uniqueID">
    try {
      var fields = Array();
      .....
    }
    </script>
```

Now I have changed the function to this:

```
var script = document.getElementById(uniqueID);
    function functionName(fieldId){
      var allFields = eval('fields'); // now here...how do I scope this by using the script var that I've created above?
....
    }
```

So, how can I scope my allFields var to a specific script tag?

Comment: The way you're defining `fields` shouldn't be working.  You don't need to wrap in a `try` block, and you should be using `fields.push({id:1,type:text,value:banana})`, etc

Comment: Why don't you just pass the `fields` array as an argument to the function.

Comment: The array is not generated by my code, I cannot change it, but it all DOES work. The function gets the ID as long as there is only ONE instance of the script tag around. Once more scripts are added with the same var of array it still works...but it always gets the same array, instead of a specific one.

Comment: @Barmar that is my question, how? I want to pass a the array from a SPECIFIC script tag, which was identified by an ID.

Comment: So many bugs... use new Array() or [], push the objects to the array, make direct assignment instead of eval, use filter method...

Comment: @Amir: you really really should fix the code that generates these `<script>` elements. Seriously. This is a bug, report it if it's not your code.

Comment: @Bergi I know it's ugly as hell.... it's not my code... I cannot get it changed w/o going through 5 levels of bureaucracy. I just have to get this working and out of my hair.

Comment: @Amir: Just saying that it would be worth it going through those 5 levels… Even if you make an `evil` workaround, you should still do it.

Comment: Btw, why are you trying to avoid `eval`? It's exactly the right tool to parse a script.

Comment: @Bergi I wouldn't care if it was used if I could scope it to a specific tag. But I don't think there's a way to do that.

Comment: @Amir: Just get the `script` element that you need, get its text content (beware of browser-specifics), and `eval` that string - then access `fields` in the scope in which you evaled.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty gross, but you can use a regular expression to parse the `script` block, assuming it always generates it in the same format.

```
function functionName(scriptID, fieldID) {
    var lines = $('#' + scriptID).text().split('\n')
    var result;
    $.each(lines, function(i, e) {
        var match = e.match(/field = (\{.*\})/);
        if (match) {
            var obj = eval(match[1]);
            if (obj.id == fieldID) {
                result = obj;
                return false; // Tell `$.each` to stop
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is going to work. Is this looking inside the fields array? And then looking to match the ID inside the array?

Comment: I guess I was hoping there was something like: var script = document.getElementById(uniqueID); var fields = $(script).find('fields')... but I guess that's a no go?

Comment: No, it's not looking in the array. It's parsing the Javascript directly.

Comment: Thje problem is that each Javascript block is overwriting the `fields` variable. So when your code runs, it will just contain the values from the last Javascript block.

Comment: That's a no-go. `.find()` looks for DOM elements, it doesn't know anything about parsing Javascript.

Comment: yea you're totally right... I guess while the ID on the script tag helps me drill into the tag... it does nothing to protect the fields array, that's just a global variable polluting the document...agh...